# Appending to SQL text field with Access DB

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access

So, there's a notes field in a table I'm accessing, and I want to be able to add to that field whenever I want. I've been using:

```
UPDATE Incident_Reports SET Incident_Note = Incident_Note + '%s' WHERE Incident_ID=%s", NoteText, IncidentID
```

This works ONLY if data exists in Incident Note, if nothing is in there, it simply does nothing.

Does anyone have any insight on this? I appreciate it!

I'm accessing a .mdb file if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the string concatenator in Jet SQL is & not +.  Using + is useful in some cases, but it generally leads to problems.

```
UPDATE Incident_Reports 
SET Incident_Note = Incident_Note & '%s' 
WHERE Incident_ID=%s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE 
  Incident_Reports 
SET 
  Incident_Note = Nz(Incident_Note, '') + '%s' 
WHERE 
  Incident_ID=%s
```

The problem is a NULL + a value always equals a NULL.  The Nz() function takes two parameters, and will return the first one if it is not null, otherwise will return the second.  In this case, it allows you to return an empty string rather than a null, which you can append to.